# Qt png file and window style

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to change the style of the main window of the program from the standard style to the style of the png file (so that the window's appearance was like in the launcher of some online games)?

something like this (the best example from game GW2)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to establish that image as a background?

Comment: I want the window of my program to be like a picture above

Comment: That is very ambiguous, explain yourself better.

Comment: Ok, I have a similar window - where you need to enter a login and password, I want to know how to make it so that the picture goes beyond the window, as in the picture on the right

Comment: No, right I try do this , and I get : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ATfkMtB1GZH8p_Si3ZUvIg7xdcha6ERH

Comment: I would try QtQuick / QML for this, you should be able to click this together in Qt Quick Designer (part of QtCreator).

Answer (score 4):

You don't do this sort of thing by making the image somehow spill out of the window, you do it by making a window large enough to hold the image and making the window background transparent.  The Qt way to do this is using the Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground window flag (together with FramelessWindowHint).

Comment: Thnx for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
ui->setupUi(this);
this->resize(1280,950);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

this->setStyleSheet("#centralWidget { "
                    " border-image: url(:/gw2.png);"
                    "}");

connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), qApp, 
SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK2cn.jpg)